# decision feedback equalizer building blocks (from Adaptive Filters: Theory and Applications” a book by Behrouz Farhang-Boroujeny)

Tags: digital-communications, adaptive-filters, equalization, equalizer

Here you can see building blocks of DFE from **"Adaptive Filters: Theory and Applications”** a book by Behrouz Farhang-Boroujeny in chapter 17.

Figure 17.9 shows the overall building blocks of DFE which in the input we have noisy signal x that passed through channel and feeds to equalizer to have an estimated version of transmitted symbols at the output.

Figure 17.22 illustrates the more detailed version of the previous one.

Figure 17.9 demonstrates how theory of multirate signal processing can be used to replace the cascade of $P_{R}(z)$ and the twofold decimator by the corresponding polyphase structure.

I put the Matlab code from book which compares Symbol-Spaced, Fractionally spaced and DF equalizers.

Now my questions are:

In figure 17.22

1- Why a two fold decimator have been used?

2-Why a delayed version of $s(n)$ has been subtracted before $W_{FB}(z)$.

3- In the code: optimum wights had been calculated for every L sample of channel which made me confused how to calculate the overall tap wights of FF and FB. Meaning, what should I do in order to pass noisy symbols from channel and DF equalizer while optimum tap wights calculated for every L sample of channel?

unfortunately, the code lacks a test demo to show how all these thing works.
https://github.com/YangangCao/AdaptiveFilter/blob/master/AdaptiveFilters/equalizer_eval.m

[image]

[image]

[image]